# Executor framework - Producer Consumer pattern

Tags: java, multithreading, design-patterns, io, executorservice

It is mentioned by [Java_author](http://jcip.net/) in section 5.3.1,

> ... many producer-consumer designs can be expressed using the `Executor` task execution framework, **which itself** uses the producer-consumer pattern.
>
> ... The producer-consumer pattern offers a **thread-friendly means** of decomposing the *problem* into simpler components(if possible).

---

Does [Executor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) framework implementation internally follow producer-consumer pattern?

If yes, How the idea of producer-consumer pattern helps in implementation of  [Executor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) framework?

Comment: You can have a look in ThreadPoolExecutor class.

Comment: @BongCon Currently in Part 1, final chapter . Am yet to start Part 2 that talks about `ThreadPoolExecutor`. It would be difficult to jump directly to Part 2.

Comment: It is indeed Producer Consumer pattern isn't?.. Main class will Produce the task to get executed and Executor will consume that task by executing it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check implementation of [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.java/?v=source)

```
public void execute(Runnable command) {
    int c = ctl.get();
    if (workerCountOf(c) < corePoolSize) {
        if (addWorker(command, true))
            return;
        c = ctl.get();
    }
    if (isRunning(c) && workQueue.offer(command)) {
        int recheck = ctl.get();
        if (! isRunning(recheck) && remove(command))
            reject(command);
        else if (workerCountOf(recheck) == 0)
            addWorker(null, false);
    }
    else if (!addWorker(command, false))
        reject(command);
}
```

Now check

```
private boolean addWorker(Runnable firstTask, boolean core) {
     // After some checks, it creates Worker and start the thread
    Worker w = new Worker(firstTask);
    Thread t = w.thread;

   // After some checks, thread has been started
   t.start();
}
```

Implementation of `Worker`:

```
  /**
     * Class Worker mainly maintains interrupt control state for
     * threads running tasks, along with other minor bookkeeping.
     * This class opportunistically extends AbstractQueuedSynchronizer
     * to simplify acquiring and releasing a lock surrounding each
     * task execution.  This protects against interrupts that are
     * intended to wake up a worker thread waiting for a task from
     * instead interrupting a task being run.  We implement a simple
     * non-reentrant mutual exclusion lock rather than use ReentrantLock
     * because we do not want worker tasks to be able to reacquire the
     * lock when they invoke pool control methods like setCorePoolSize.
     */
    private final class Worker
        extends AbstractQueuedSynchronizer
        implements Runnable
    {

      /** Delegates main run loop to outer runWorker  */
       public void run() {
            runWorker(this);
       }

    final void runWorker(Worker w) {
          Runnable task = w.firstTask;
          w.firstTask = null;
          boolean completedAbruptly = true;
    try {
        while (task != null || (task = getTask()) != null) {
            w.lock();
            clearInterruptsForTaskRun();
            try {
                beforeExecute(w.thread, task);
                Throwable thrown = null;
                try {
                    task.run();
                } catch (RuntimeException x) {
                    thrown = x; throw x;
                } catch (Error x) {
                    thrown = x; throw x;
                } catch (Throwable x) {
                    thrown = x; throw new Error(x);
                } finally {
                    afterExecute(task, thrown);
                }
            } finally {
                task = null;
                w.completedTasks++;
                w.unlock();
            }
        }
        completedAbruptly = false;
    } finally {
        processWorkerExit(w, completedAbruptly);
    }
```

Which `Runnable` to execute is dependent on below logic.

```
/**
 * Performs blocking or timed wait for a task, depending on
 * current configuration settings, or returns null if this worker
 * must exit because of any of:
 * 1. There are more than maximumPoolSize workers (due to
 *    a call to setMaximumPoolSize).
 * 2. The pool is stopped.
 * 3. The pool is shutdown and the queue is empty.
 * 4. This worker timed out waiting for a task, and timed-out
 *    workers are subject to termination (that is,
 *    {@code allowCoreThreadTimeOut || workerCount > corePoolSize})
 *    both before and after the timed wait.
 *
 * @return task, or null if the worker must exit, in which case
 *         workerCount is decremented
 */
private Runnable getTask() {
     // After some checks, below code returns Runnable

      try {
            Runnable r = timed ?
                workQueue.poll(keepAliveTime, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS) :
                workQueue.take();
            if (r != null)
                return r;
            timedOut = true;
        } catch (InterruptedException retry) {
            timedOut = false;
        }
}
```

In Summary:

1. **Producer** adds `Runnable` or `Callable` in `execute` API with `workQueue.offer(command)`
2. `execute()` method creates `Worker` thread if needed
3. This `Worker` thread runs in infinite loop. It gets task (e.g. `Runnable`) from `getTask()`
4. `getTask()` pools on `BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue)` and take `Runnable`. It is **consumer** of `BlockingQueue`.

> Does Executor framework implementation internally follow producer-consumer pattern?

Yes as explained above.

> If yes, How the idea of producer-consumer pattern helps in implementation of Executor framework?

`BlockingQueue` implementation like `ArrayBlockingQueue` and `ExecutorService` implementation`ThreadPoolExecutor` are thread safe. Overhead on programmer on explicit implementation of synchronized, wait and notify calls to implement the same has been reduced.

Comment: So, `Worker` thread was initially created(< `corePoolSize`) due to initial `command` passed to `execute()`. After my command completes execution on this `Worker` thread the same `Worker` thread picks new task from queue. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes. corePoolSize will be increased later.

Comment: So, In this [code](https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J5e_multithreading.html#zz-7.4), running `java ThreadPoolTest 5 2`, creates `workQueue` of size 5 and `workers` of size 2 as members of  `ThreadPoolExecutor`'s instance. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

`Executor framework` uses `producer-consumer` pattern.

From Wikipedia,

> *In computing, the producer–consumer problem (also known as the
>   bounded-buffer problem) is a classic example of a multi-process
>   synchronization problem. The problem describes two processes, the
>   producer and the consumer, who share a common, fixed-size buffer used
>   as a queue. The producer's job is to generate data, put it into the
>   buffer, and start again. At the same time, the consumer is consuming
>   the data (i.e., removing it from the buffer), one piece at a time. The
>   problem is to make sure that the producer won't try to add data into
>   the buffer if it's full and that the consumer won't try to remove data
>   from an empty buffer.*

If we have a look on different `ExecutorService framework` implementations, more specifically `ThreadPoolExecutor` class, it basically has the following:

1. A queue, where the jobs are submitted and held
2. Number of threads which consumes the tasks submitted to the queue.

Based on the type of the executor service, these parameters changes

For example,

- Fixed thread pool uses a `LinkedBlockingQueue` and user configured no of threads
- Cached Thread pool uses a `SynchronousQueue` and no of threads between `0` to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` based on the number of submitted tasks